# Rails habtm nested select doesn't has right selected value on edit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, select, nested, has-and-belongs-to-many, selected

I have the following models in my RoR project:
 scope and project_scopes.

Project `has_many :scopes, through: :project_scopes`. Also project `accepts_nested_attributes_for :project_scopes`.

I add scopes to projects by several selects:

**projects/_form.html.haml**

```
= form_for(@project) do |f|
  = f.fields_for :project_scopes do |builder|
    = render 'project_scope_fields', f: builder
  = link_to_add_fields 'Add scopes', f, :project_scopes
```

**projects/project_scope_fields.html.haml**

```
= f.select :scope_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@scopes, "id", "name"), {include_blank: true, class: "project_scopes"}
= f.hidden_field :_destroy
```

This successfully creates projects with all scopes. When I click edit, it renders same form and displays all scope selects, but they do not have the correct selected value.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 4):

Look at the documentation for [options_from_collection_for_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-option_groups_from_collection_for_select): It takes 4 parameters, the last one being the selected option. You're not supplying that. Try this:

```
= f.select :scope_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@scopes, "id", "name", @project.scope)
```

or simply use the [collection_select](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-collection_select) helper:

```
= f.collection_select(:scope_id, @scopes, :id, :name)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following (and I'm assuming, you're setting `attr_accessible` correctly):

```
= f.select :scope_id, @scopes.map{|s| [s.name, s.id]}, {include_blank: true, class: "project_scopes"}
```

Btw - `Scope` may not be best model name.